# How to Get the value of Inferred Object Property in OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl, owl-api, reasoner

I have an ontology created in Protege, with classes and properties and related instances for them. 
Considering one object property I want to find all the instances in the ontology sharing the same object property - to do that I did iterate through abject properties and got the value of each of them and got the individual sharing same properties.

The problem I'm facing in is by this method I can not get the values for the inferred properties.

To make it more clear, in the following image; 
For the property **isFrom** I can get the value of **761** which is fine, however for the property **immediateRelation**I was expecting to get **GroupOfPeople2** but I got empty. So for **participant** and **immediateRelation** which are inferred relation, I can not get any value.

Can you please help me with any method that let me go through the values of inferred properties as well ?

Following is part of the code I used for getting values.

[The part of result I got when I turn the reasoner on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibtBf.png)

```
for (OWLObjectProperty ax: listObjectProperty) {
  TreeSet < OWLNamedIndividual > finalInd_sameOProperty = new
  TreeSet < OWLNamedIndividual > ();
  for (OWLNamedIndividual i:
    individualsameProperty) {
    Set < OWLNamedIndividual > objectValue = reasoner.getObjectPropertyValues(i, ax).getFlattened();
    if (objectValue.size() > 0) {
      finalInd_sameOProperty.add(i);

    }

  }
```

Comment: Are the properties `immediateRelation` and `Participant` contained in the list of properties `listObjectProperty`?

Comment: Yes of course. This list contains all the object properties in the ontology.

Comment: Then the code should work. Which reasoner do you use? Can you share the ontology? Which OWL API version?

Comment: I'm using owlapi version 4.2.3. I want to use Hermit reasoner and for that, 
using the following; 

'OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new 
 StructuralReasonerFactory();
 OWLReasonerConfiguration config = new SimpleConfiguration();
 OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ontology, config); '

Comment: Ehm, that's indeed wrong. `StructuralReasonerFactory` is **not** the HermiT reasoner nor any other OWL DL reasoner. It's just an OWL API internal implementation of the `OWLReasoner` interface that works on the asserted axioms + some light-weight transitive closure of the class and property hierarchy. The HermiT reasoner factory is `org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory`

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

For using the pellet I used the following code , 

OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = PelletReasonerFactory.getInstance();  
Is it same for Hermit?

WLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = HermiT.ReasonerFactory.getInstance();

Comment: If it doesn't compile, obviously not ... you resp. your IDE should be able to determine whether there is a static method or not. Otherwise, it's the usual Java way to use the `new` operator, right? Each reasoner just implements the `OWLReasoner` interface and maybe provides a factory.  How this factory is created is not fixed as there are several ways in Java. For HermiT this one should work: `new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory();` with the import `import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner;`